# Getting null while uploading multiple images in Laravel

Tags: laravel, file-upload

I am getting null while I tried to upload multiple images in Laravel 8.

```
 In Blade:

<form method="POST" action="{{ url('admin/add_images/'.$album_id.'/save') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <input name="image_name[]" type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
```

In Controller

```
 function save_image(Request $req, $id)
  {
     $gallery =  new GalleryImage();  
    return $req->file('image_name') ;
  }
```

I browse 2 images and upload.

[I got this output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5vJo.png)

Comment: You do nothing with $gallery

Comment: @Maksim I want to check how many files are posted. It is doing nothing with $gallery. It is model object

Comment: You should use spatie to handle your uploads ... it will make your life so much easier and will also take care of all the security issues you could encounter. https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary